# Accessing past user locations in Android

Tags: android, location

I'm planning to write an app that needs to know where the user went (i.e. her location data) during the two weeks prior to the first use of the app. The app is being used to run a human-mobility simulation algorithm and it requires two weeks of "training data." I'm considering writing the app on Android.

I am aware that with various Location Strategies (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) and/or addons like the GPS Logger (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mendhak.gpslogger&hl=en), I can start logging location data from the *moment* the user starts using the app, but I need data from the *past*. Does Android automatically track user location data in a way that can be accessed, and if so, how? I know that at some point it was realized that iPhones track user location data (I don't know if they still do), and I was wondering if Android did a similar thing.

Thank you.

Comment: are you looking for last known location in android ?

Comment: I'm looking for as many previous locations as possible, if Android stores them automatically. i.e. If you started the app now, I want to access location data starting from two weeks ago up till now.